# TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type "name of interface"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem in typescript file (Angular), when I want to set attribute of interface to null, it shows error (picture), I saw this on one site and it's working there, I can't resolve what is problem here, any kind of help will be welcome

Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM1w4.png

Comment: Check your project's `tsconfig.json` file to see if `strictNullCheck` is enabled. That may be one cause for this error.

Comment: I should note that keeping `strictNullCheck` enabled is recommended. While it can be a pain to work with, it helps prevent a great number of possible errors. Especially `Cannot read property of null` errors.